# mips - difference in methods for accessing arrays

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I am currently trying to learn the MIPS assembly language and have come accross two different ways in using arrays and would like to know the difference, if any, between the two.

first method

```
          .data
array:    .word    0, 1, 2, 3
          .text
main:
    li    $t0, 0
    lw    $t1, array($t0) #t1 = array[0], t1 = 0
    addi  $t0, $t0, 4     #increment
    lw    $t2, array($t0) #t2 = array[1], t2 = 1
```

second method

```
          .data
array:    .word    0, 1, 2, 3
          .text
main:
    la    $t0, array
    lw    $t1, ($t0) #t1 = 0
    addi  $t0, t0, 4 #increment
    lw    $t2, ($t0) #t2 = 1
```

So whats the difference?

Comment: One you are loading the address of the array to $t0 which starts at 0, and the other you are just loading 0. No difference, besides readability and I think standard is first method.

Comment: The second method is the normal method. The first method only works if the address of array is less than 64kbytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference is that, depending on the location in memory of `array` relative to the `lw` instruction, that `lw` could be a pseudo-instruction that gets translated into multiple actual instructions.

The encoding of an `lw` instruction (`lw rt, offset(base)`) is:

```
------------------------------- 
| 100011 | base | rt | offset |
-------------------------------
```

The offset part is 16 bits and will be sign-extended to 32 bits, so it has a range of -32768..+32767. That's the maximum possible distance that you can have between `array` and the `lw` instruction, and still have the `lw` instruction assemble into just an `lw` instruction.
If the distance is greater - which it most likely is in your case since `array` and the `lw` instruction are located in different sections - the assembler might treat the `lw` as a pseudo-instruction and translate it into 2, 3, or 4 actual instructions. Some assemblers might not support this and just treat it as an error instead.

An example of what the translation might look like:

```
# array located at 0x10010000
# lw $t1,array($t0) located at 0x00400018

lui $at,0x1001     # $at = 0x10010000
addu $at,$at,$t0   # $at = 0x10010000 + $t0
lw $t1,($t0)
```